# Привязка данных в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mvvm

Добрый вечер форумчане! Начал вот изучать WPF и столкнулся с непонятностью. Допустим в asp.net mvc если я имею такую разметку:

```
<form action='someAction' >
    <input type=text name='Name' >
    <select name='Age' />
    <input type='submit' value='Save' />
</form>
```

такую модель:

```
class MyModel 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    public int Id{get; set;}    
}
```

и такой экшен контроллера:

```
public ActionResult someAction(MyModel model)
{
    // ...
}
```

То с помощью механизма привязки модели в AS.NET при нажатии на сабмит я в экшене someAction я получу полностью сконфигурированную из разметки модель MyModel. 
Но никак не могу понять как сделать то же самое в ЦЗА хотя там вроде бы все как раз завязано на привязках данных. Пытался сделать это с помощью MultiBinding и IMultiValueConverter но ничего не получилось - привязка почему-то происходит при загрузке приложения, а не при нажатии на кнопку. Подскажите знающие люди как быть?  заранее спасибо

Comment: Разница в том, что ASP.NET не имеет возможности хранить состояние объектов, а в десктопном приложении это возможно. Привязка осуществляется к объектам, которые существуют в памяти на всём протяжении привязки, а не создается во время нажатия кнопки. А для обработки нажатий можно использовать привязки к командам - объектам, реализующим интерфейс ICommand.

Comment: @Pleshkov Ivan спасибо конечно но как то слишком абстрактно говорите

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот вам простейший пример.

Объект, который вы хотите отобразить:

```
class VM : DependencyObject
{
    // это стандартное объявление dependency property
    public string Name
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(NameProperty); }
        set { SetValue(NameProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty NameProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Name", typeof(string), typeof(VM));

    // добавьте другие property по вкусу
}
```

Теперь, View:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

Во View-объекте `DataContext` должен быть вашим объектом `VM`. При этом содержимое `Name` будут показано на нужном месте UI и будет автоматически обновляться.

Данные в WPF bind'ятся (то есть, обновляются при изменении связанного элемента UI) *всё время*, а не только по нажатию на кнопку. По нажатию на кнопку вы можете, однако, считать их, и выполнить на их основе какие-нибудь действия.

Дальнейшие подробности легко находятся в гугле (лучше искать на английском). Ключевые слова: `Binding`, Dependency Property, MVVM.

Comment: @VladD, почему в большинстве ваших ответов на подобную тему вы биндитесь через `DependencyObject`? Какой в этом смысл - мы ведь не пишем собственный контрол? 

Гораздо приятней и удобней ведь реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged`

Comment: @Veikedo: А почему бы и нет? У `DependencyObject`'а есть явная thread affinity, и это хорошо, это раз. Dependency property не занимает места, если не используется, два. На них можно навешивать coercion и validation (как это по-русски?), три. В остальном не вижу разницы, разве только для `INotifyPropertyChanged` больше печатать (для dependency property есть готовый snippet).

Comment: @VladD, спасиб, понял. 

Для `INotifyPropertyChanged` у решарпера тоже сниппет есть

Comment: @Veikedo: В принципе, сниппеты можно добавлять самостоятельно и без решарпера. С другой стороны, большинство MVVM-фреймворков имеют собственный базовый класс для VM, так что если пользуетесь фреймворком, выбор сделан за вас.

Comment: @VladD, у решарпера есть конвертация свойств в свойства с вызовом оповещения об изменении.

Для совсем ленивых можно вообще AOP подход использовать :) Мне нравится, кстати.

https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged
http://www.postsharp.net/